# Объединить 1-канальные изображения

Tags: python, opencv

Есть два серых (1-канальных) изображения, нужно превратить их в 3-канальное, поместив первое изображение, например, на R канал, а второе на G канал. Как это правильно сделать в python'е (используя библиотеку OpenCV, но можно и без неё)?

Comment: на  Pillow просто `Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b)).save(file, "JPEG") ` это если уже images. Или можно создать из списков, тоже просто